# Sync audio volume between VM and host

Tags: vmware-workstation

Currently using VMware Workstation 12, with audio playing on my host.

Is there a way to sync audio volume between my guest and host.

Comment: I'd also like to know this. @JB_STWUK, have you found out anything perhaps since?

Answer (score 0):

If no solution exists for this problem yet, I imagine we could make this work by figuring out a comm channel between the host and guest (if nothing else, share a file containing the desired volume, and run a little script periodically for checking (polling) both the 'file' and the local system volume, and also tracking the last checked local system volume.

Based on these 3 variables, we can decide whether to update the file or update the local volume. So if we set up this comm channel, and run the utility scripts on both os-es, then the volume will be synced, say every 1 second (or 0.1s, depending on how frequent we can make the polling).

Or if we can hook up event handlers for the local system volume, and/or 'shared-file' change (inotify), perhaps even close to instantly.

2 additional benefits for this approach:

1. This is versatile enough to sync volumes between any 2 os-es, (not just VMWare, VirtualBox could work too), and not even just between VM guest/host, e.g. if we use Dropbox or similar for the comm channel, file sharing.
2. It could sync between more than 2 OSes at a time, because the vector/origin of the change is always clear: It's coming from a single source, and all others follow.

Maybe we could add play/pause syncing too.

Now I wonder if this is perhaps implemented in Synergy or similar software.